# Почему не работает float: right;?

Tags: css

```
.sidebar2 {
  font-family: Chocolate cyr-lat;
  color: #0A0E18;
  background-color: #F2A90E;
  border: 2px solid #DF9600;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 9px #D76C1A;
  font-family: VAG World;
  font-size: small;
  width: 17%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 219px;
  height: 442px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute;` и `float:` - это разные подходы к позиционированию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Float` - зависимое позиционное состояние, которое зависит от позиции родителя. Это значит что оно не совместимо с `position:absolute` свойством, так как `position:absolute` является абсолютным позиционным состоянием.

Используйте:

```
position:absolute;
right: 0;
```

Также убедитесь что у родительского элемента установлено `position:relative;`.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11333667/6677992)

Comment: "зависимое позиционное состояние, которое зависит от позиции родителя"... - float строго не зависит  от позиции родителя, а лишь говорит "выровнять элемент в потоке". float и position: absolute - взаимоисключающие.

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` - абсолютное позиционирования элемента относительно родителя. Если у родителя не указано `position: relative;`, то позиционирование будет относительно окна.

`float` - определяет, по какой стороне будет выравниваться элемент. При этом остальные элементы "обтекают" его. Удобно для позиционирования картинок в тексте.

```js
(function() {
  var $sidebar = $('.sidebar')
  $sidebar.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('demo')
  })
})()
```

```css
wrapper {
  width: 100VW;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: transform .2s;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.sidebar>div {
  padding: 1.2rem;
}

.sidebar.demo {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div>
      <h2>i'm sidebar</h2>
      <p>click on me</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="float">
 <img style="float: left; margin: 0 .5rem .5rem 0" src="https://loremflickr.com/190/90">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </p>
 </div>
```